# What's the best way to play the worst possible 4 hands in bridge

Tags: bridge, puzzles

1. Everyone has 5-4-4
2. Every pair has a 5-0 match and two 4-4.
3. Every 5 long colors is 10-A.

How do you play this and what's the maximum you can achive?

Comment: If you have a specific hand in mind, write it out properly. This description looks like a generic description of a moderately large family of similar hands.

Comment: Because ice cream has no bones. In other words, I have no idea what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Why not use a bridge solver?

Answer (score 2):

These hands are pathological for both sides. For example consider this example of one pattern you describe:

```
            NORTH
            S: AKQJT        
            H: -
            D: AQT8
            C: KJ97

WEST                    EAST
S: 8642                S: 9753
H: 9753                H: 8642
D: J9753               D: -
C: -                   C: J9753

            SOUTH
            S: -        
            H: AKQJT
            D: KJ97
            C: AQT8
```

Although NS can make 7NT on any lead, if they mistakenly end up in 7 of a major instead the result will be anything from making to down 8, depending on the lead. (Note the cross ruff in the minors available to EW if either major is trump.) Note that many NS pairs may find it difficult to reach the cold Notrump grand with a void in each hand.

A Diamond contract by South is unassailable as East has no diamonds with which to ruff, but by North will go down one on a Club lead by East. The opposite holds true for a Club contract.

The actual result at each table will very much depend on the experience and systems available to each partnership.

The (in)famous [Mississippi Heart Hand](http://www.bridgeace.com/Lessons/famous/The_Mississippi_Heart_Hand.pdf) is another example of a pathologically bad distribution for a seemingly very strong  partnership holding.

Comment: Thanks but my description was much more specific (and even more pathological): Every 5 long colors is 10-A. I think the first interesting question in that case is: do you open at all? It'll be hard especially on the 3rd seat not to... for eg. by rule of 22 you have 10 HCP + 9 in longest suits + 2 quick tricks = 21. And to answer, if you count losers, you only have 6... so in a typical hand a game is very likely and a small slam is possible. How do you count your hand to stop? Etc